# Why I get a 400 bad request with an auth request to Twitter?

Tags: api, twitter, oauth

This is the resource I calling for:

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json&count%3D2%26oauth_consumer_key%3DVnNeRUCEZAEQFgSR6j7RA%26oauth_nonce%3D47ce3f3bc553afa24qwwWsa6d651d697407d279%26oauth_signature_method%3DHAS12MAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D13739599ASdas95%26oauth_token%3D1041as30304-HEYQ1S65ybBYP2J1Xey1sK7xql1nyU2ykZDr9txA%26oauth_version%3D1.0%26screen_name%3DMyAgency
```

but I get an empty page with `NetworkError: 400 Bad Request`.

Where am I wrong? And where do I check this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This status code will be returned during version 1.0 rate limiting. In API v1.1, a request without authentication is considered invalid and you will get this response.

If you're using version 1.0 - The Twitter API only allows clients to make a limited number of calls in a given hour. This policy affects the APIs in different ways.

Comment: But it should be valid: I pass the oauth access token. I just get the code from OAuth Tool/OAuth signing results (copy and paste, with URI decoding)

Comment: Ok, I see I can do request only server side, adding to the header of the request the Bearer access token! So, since i'm authenticate, there are no limits on search/request?

Comment: @markzzz i believe the limit is 350 req/h but please recheck that.